# How to get all text in inside div parent with xpath

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath

I want to get all text inside a div with xpath

Here HTML code:

```
<div class="JobDescriptionsc__DescriptionContainer-sc-1jylha1-2 dGyoDf">
 <div class="DraftEditorContainersc__DraftEditorContainer-sc-1x4uima-0 cGUaQf">
  <div class="DraftEditor-root">
   <div class="DraftEditor-editorContainer">
    <div class="public-DraftEditor-content" contenteditable="false" spellcheck="false" style="outline:none;user-select:text;-webkit-user-select:text;white-space:pre-wrap;word-wrap:break-word">
     <div data-contents="true">
       #Here the all text
        <div class="" data-block="true" data-editor="d54la" data-offset-key="bhkoa-0-0">
         <div data-offset-key="bhkoa-0-0" class="public-DraftStyleDefault-block public-DraftStyleDefault-ltr">
          <span data-offset-key="bhkoa-0-0" style="font-weight:bold">
           <span data-text="true">Job Description:</span>
          </span>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="" data-block="true" data-editor="d54la" data-offset-key="51e5u-0-0">
         <div data-offset-key="51e5u-0-0" class="public-DraftStyleDefault-block public-DraftStyleDefault-ltr">
          <span data-offset-key="51e5u-0-0">
           <span data-text="true">· Identify &amp; developed application base on predefined business requirements.</span>
           </span>
          </div>
         </div>
         ...
         #there's more, I'm just showing you a few
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

This my XPath code:

```
dom_job.xpath('//*[@class="DraftEditorContainersc__DraftEditorContainer-sc-1x4uima-0 cGUaQf"]//text()')
```

I need the all text inside the div parent with xpath, can it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the Python module which provides your XPath interpreter supports XPath version 1. Your XPath expression below returns the set of all text nodes which are descendants of the `div` element:

```xml
//*[@class="DraftEditorContainersc__DraftEditorContainer-sc-1x4uima-0 cGUaQf"]//text()
```

You should be able to iterate over all that collection of text nodes, and concatenate them into a single string, in Python.

But it's simpler, if you want the concatenated value of the text nodes within a particular `div`, to just apply the XPath `string()` function to the `div`; e.g.:

```xml
string(//*[@class="DraftEditorContainersc__DraftEditorContainer-sc-1x4uima-0 cGUaQf"])
```

See https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-string

Note that, in XPath 1, if you apply the `string()` function to a larger set of nodes (such as the set of text nodes returned by your first query), the function will return the string value of *just the first* node.